# Measuring multiple incidences of a continuous constant in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I had a hard time trying to word this question properly; I apologize...

So I have a (very) big list of 0's and 1's:

```
   AllTimes = {{0}, {0}, {0}, {1}, {1}, ...}
```

I want to somehow measure the number of continuous 1's (i.e., if the list is `{{0}, {1}, {1}, {0}, {1}, {0}}` I want to get the values `2` and `1`). Is there a way of running a LengthWhile as a loop to give me not just one, but all lengths of continuous 1's?

I've also (miserably) failed to program a different method:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 100000, i++, t = 0
   If[AllTimes[[{i}]] = 1,
    t = t + 1]
   If[AllTimes[[{i}]] = 0, Print[t], t = 0]]
```

I wanted each index of `AllTimes` to be read, and if it's `1`, a value of `t` is added. If the value of an index gives `0`, I want the `t` to be printed and reset back to `0`. (I'm totally new to Mathematica programming... so please be gentle...). Although instead of printing, is there a way to also store the value of `t` before it is reseted to `0`?

Thank you for taking your time to read my question...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE, I am sure someone will be able to give a good, short solution to the problem you've tried to describe in your post.

Comment: What about: `Length /@ SequenceCases[l, {{1} ..}]`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
list = {{0}, {1}, {1}, {0}, {1}, {0}};

Length /@ Cases[Split@Flatten@list, {1 ...}]
```

> {2, 1}

Comment: sorry I edited your answer by mistake - I rolled back.

Answer (score 6):

A rather new function (10.1) here:

```
l = {{0}, {1}, {1}, {0}, {1}, {0}};

Length /@ SequenceCases[l, {{1} ..}]
```

> (*  {2, 1} *)

Answer (score 4):

**Code:**

```
Length@# & /@ Cases[Split@Flatten[#, 1], {1 ...}] &[{{1}, {1}, {0}, {1}}]
```

**Output:**

> {2,1}

**Reference:**
[Length](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html?q=Length)
[@ | /@ / #](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)
[Split](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html)
[Flatten](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html?q=Flatten)
[Cases](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html?q=Cases)

Comment: Thanks for the references! It's really nice to understand how each command is used :)

Comment: You are very welcome! There is lots of useful information here on Mathematica SE.I would encourage you to visit the most up-voted question section; two posts in particular: "Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practices?" && "What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?" to get yourself up-to-speed with Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
list = {{0}, {1}, {1}, {0}, {1}, {0}};

Length /@ SequenceSplit[list, {{0}}]
```

{2, 1}

Answer (score 2):

Using `SplitBy` and `DeleteCases`:

```
l = {{0}, {1}, {1}, {0}, {1}, {0}};

Length /@ DeleteCases[SplitBy[l, {{1}}], {{0}}]

(*{2, 1}*)
```

Another way is to use [ConsecutiveQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140472/ordered-subsequences-of-consecutive-integers/140473#140473) to split by positions as follows:

```
Length@Extract[l, #] & /@ SequenceCases[Position[l, {1}], {__}?ConsecutiveQ]

(*{2, 1}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since @eldo and @E. Chan-López revived this thread a very small contribution to their efforts.

```
list = {{0}, {1}, {1}, {0}, {1}, {0}};
```

then

```
Length /@ Select[Split[Flatten[list]], Total[#] > 0 &]
```

> `{2, 1}`